# Version-control in a large SSIS ETL project

Tags: version-control, ssis

We're about to make data transformation from one system to another using SSIS. We are four people people who will continuously be working on this for two years and therefore we need some sort of versioning system. We can not use team foundation. We're currently configuring a SVN server, but digging into it I've seen some big risks.

It seems that a solution is stored in one huge XML file. This must be a huge problem in a combined code/drag and drop environment as SSIS, as it will be impossible for SVN to merge the changes correctly, and whenever we get an error when commiting we will have to look inside that huge XML file and correct the mistakes manually.

One way to solve this problem is to create many solution projects in SSIS. However, this is not really the setup we want as we are creating one big monster which will have 2 days to execute and we want to follow its progress as it executes. If we have to create several solutions are there ways to link their execution and still have a visual look of whats going on and how well the execution is doing?

Has anyone had similar problems and/or do you have any suggestions as to how to solve them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most ETL projects I work use SVN as the source control repository.  The best method I have found is to break each project or solution down into smaller, distinct (and often independently runnable) packages.  So for example, say you had a process called ManufacturingImport, this could be your project.  Within this you would have a Master package, which then called other packages as required.  This means that members of the team can work on distinct packages or pieces of work, rather than everyone trying to edit the same package and getting into troublesome situations with merging.

Comment: But behind the scenes all these packages are stored in one big file for each project right? Is it your experience that as long as you work in different packages (thus different places in the big project file) it is not a problem to make changes and commit them?

Comment: No each package is in it's own file and can therefore be committed independently to SVN.  Not sure about this one big file...do you mean the actual project file that holds the details of what packages are in each project?

Comment: Yea, i just misunderstood how the files are arranged in an SSIS project. It looks like SVN will be sufficient then as long as we split it into packages as you propose.

Answer (score 7):

Just how many packages are you talking about?  If it is hundreds of packages, then what is the specific problem you are trying to avoid?  Here are a few things you might be trying to avoid based on your post:

1. Slow solution and project load time at startup in BIDS.  I suppose this could be irritating from time to time.  But if you keep BIDS open all day, that seems like a once a day cost.
2. Slow solution and project load time when you get latest solution definition from your version control system.  Again, I suppose this could be irritating from time to time, but how frequently do you need to refresh the whole solution?  If you break the solution into separate projects, then you only need to refresh a project.  You would only need to refresh the whole solution if you want to get access to a new project within the solution.

What do you mean by "one huge XML file"?  The solution file is an XML file that keeps track of the projects.  Each project file is an XML file that keeps track of its SSIS packages.  So if you have 1,000 SSIS packages evenly distribution across 10 projects in 1 solution, then each file would have no more than 100 objects to track.  I can tell you from experience that I've had Reporting Services projects with more RDL files than this and it only took seconds to load the solution properly in BIDS.  And as @revelator pointed out, the actual SSIS packages are their own individual XML files.  Any version control system should track each of these as separate files and won't combine them into "one huge XML file".  If you clarify what you mean by this point, then I think you will get better help on the question.

Whether you are running one package or 1,000 packages, you won't be doing this interactively from BIDS.  You will probably deploy the packages to server first and then have the server run the packages.  If that's the case, then you will need to call the packages probably with a SQL Server Agent job.  Whether you chain the packages by making each package call another package or if you chain the packages by having the job call each package as a separate job step, you can still track where you are in the chain with logging.  If you are calling the packages with jobs, then you can track it with job steps too.  I run a data warehouse that has scores of packages and I primarily rely on separating processes into jobs that each contain one or more packages.  I also chain jobs with start job commands so that I can more easily monitor performance of logical groups of loads.  Also, each package shows its execution time in the job history at the step level.  Furthermore, I have custom logging in each stored procedure and package that shows how many seconds and rows an individual data load or stored procedure took so that I can troubleshoot performance bottlenecks.

Whatever you do, don't rely on running packages interactively as a way to track performance!  You won't get optimal performance running ETL on your machine, let alone running it with a GUI.  Run packages in jobs on servers, not desktops.  Interactively running packages is just their to help build and troubleshoot individual packages, not to adminster daily ETL.

If you are building generic packages that change their targets and sources based on parameters, then you probably need to build a control table in a database tha tracks progress.  If you are simply moving data from one large system to another as a one time event, then you are probably going to divide the load into small sets of packages and have separate jobs for each so that you can more easily manage recovering from failures.  If you intend to build something that runs regularly to move data, then how could 2 days of constant running for one process even make sense?  It sounds like the underlying data will change on you within 2 days...

If you are concerned about which version control system to use for managing SSIS package projects, then I can say that just about any will do.  I've used Visual SourceSafe and Perforce at different companies and both have the same basic features of checking in and checking out individual packages.  I'm sure just about any version control system that integrates with Visual Studios will do this for you.

Hope you find something useful in the above and good luck with your project.

Answer (score 7):

Version control makes it possible to have multiple people developing together and working on same project.  If I am working on something, a fellow ETL developer will not be able to check it out and make changes to it until I am finished with my changes and check those back in.   This addresses the common situation where one developer’s project artifact and code changes clobber that of another developer by accident.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/08/10/sql-server-who-needs-etl-version-control/

Comment: Not if it's a dtsx file. You can merge the changes but when you open the file in VS it will not open and be corrupt.